# My prefabs in unity aren't running script when spawned after one another (uses XR controller)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Similar to most people on here I'm fairly new to the unity scene and I'm attempting to create a specific mechanism in my game: I want to create a bush where I can spawn fruit items from; the fruit on the bush take a specific amount of time to grow and can't be interacted with until they're fully grown. Once grown as soon as you grab the fruit, it spawns another in the position of the original to repeats the cycle.

However, how the code works is it spawns a first fruit, grows and interacts once grown but once I grab the first fruit, the plant stops growing and just shows the fully grown object(however after every time you grab that fruit it spawns another fruit as intended) ,this object doesn't react with gravity unlike the original which applies gravity after interaction.

The object is a prefab and contains the following script:

```
using System.Collections; using System.Collections.Generic;

using UnityEngine; using UnityEngine.XR.Interaction.Toolkit;

public class GrowthScript : MonoBehaviour { Collider ObjectCol; [SerializeField] private GameObject Item;

 public int GrowTime = 6;
 public float MinSize = 0.1f;
 public float MaxSize = 1f;
 public float Timer = 0f;
 private XRGrabInteractable grabInteractable = null;
 
 public bool IsMaxSize = false;
 public bool CanRegrow = false;
 // Start is called before the first frame update
 void Start()
 {
     Debug.Log("Growing");
     IsMaxSize = false;
     ObjectCol = GetComponent<Collider>();
     // if the plant isnt full size, it starts a routine to grow
     if (IsMaxSize == false)
     {
         ObjectCol.enabled = !ObjectCol.enabled;
         StartCoroutine(Grow());
     }
 }
 private void Awake()
 {
     grabInteractable = GetComponent<XRGrabInteractable>();
     grabInteractable.onSelectEntered.AddListener(Obtain);
     
 }
 private IEnumerator Grow()
 {
     Vector3 startScale = new Vector3(MinSize, MinSize, MinSize);
     Vector3 maxScale = new Vector3(MaxSize, MaxSize, MaxSize);
     do
     {
         transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(startScale, maxScale, Timer / GrowTime);
         Timer += Time.deltaTime;
         yield return null;
     }
     while (Timer < GrowTime);
     IsMaxSize = true;
     CanRegrow = true;
     Debug.Log("Grown");
     ObjectCol.enabled = !ObjectCol.enabled;
 }
 private void Obtain(XRBaseInteractor interactor)
 {
     if (CanRegrow == true)
     {
         
         GameObject instance = Instantiate(Item, transform.position, transform.rotation) as GameObject;
         CanRegrow = false;
     }
 }
}
```

It would be Deeply appreciated if I could receive help on why the prefab doesn't run the code on respawn or a way to solve the problem.

Much appreciated (Good Luck)

Comment: How is the first fruit spawned? Its in the scene already? The second one is an instance of a prefab so is the prefab different from the one in the scene i.e. any of the serialized/public field have different values? Oh and is the prefab (item) in the project and not refering to the one in the scene?

Comment: So the problem is related to the object not interacting with the gravity? You should check the collider, maybe make a field reference so you can ref it from inspector and save to the prefab instance. You may easily have more colliders on your fruit so you should be sure you enable the correct one. Also XR components may change colliders and physics parameter so it is a good idea to set those parameters again, maybe with some delay to be sure your script act upon them after other components. Try to enable collider explicitly `collider.enabled = true`. And maybe some other rigidbody settings too